AWS CodePipeline getting stuck on Deploy stage with my NestJS backend
I'm trying to deploy my NestJS backend using AWS CodePipeline, but I'm encountering some issues during the deployment stage. The build stage passes successfully, but the deployment fails with the following error in the logs:
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2024-08-09T10_24_04_389Z-debug-0.log

2024/08/09 10:24:08.432829 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/su webapp -c npm --omit=dev install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
gyp info using node@20.12.2 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.16 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args '/usr/lib/node_modules_20/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-f',
gyp info spawn args 'make',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/var/app/staging/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/var/app/staging/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/usr/lib/node_modules_20/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/home/webapp/.cache/node-gyp/20.12.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/webapp/.cache/node-gyp/20.12.2',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules_20/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/webapp/.cache/node-gyp/20.12.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/app/staging',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args 'build',
gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-addon-api'
Require stack:
- /var/app/staging/[eval]
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at runScriptInThisContext (node:internal/vm:209:10)
    at node:internal/process/execution:109:14
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:24
    at runScript (node:internal/process/execution:92:62)
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:123:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/app/staging/[eval]' ]
}

Node.js v20.12.2
gyp: Call to 'node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules_20/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:271:18)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 6.1.97-104.177.amzn2023.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node-20" "/usr/lib/node_modules_20/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/app/staging
gyp ERR! node -v v20.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/app/staging
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2024-08-09T10_24_04_389Z-debug-0.log
 

2024/08/09 10:24:08.432836 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2024/08/09 10:24:08.432953 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: The deployment used the default Node.js version for your platform version instead of the Node.js version included in your 'package.json'.","timestamp":1723199042917,"severity":"WARN"},{"msg":"Instance deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1723199048432,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1723199048432,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}


here you can also have a look at my buildspec and package.json files
buildspec.yml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 20.16.0
    commands:
      - npm install -g @nestjs/cli
      - npm install
      - npm uninstall @prisma/cli 
      - npm install prisma --save-dev 
      - npm i node-gyp@3.8.0
      - npm install node-addon-api --save

  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Build completed on `date`"

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/**/*

env:
  variables:
    DATABASE_URL: $DATABASE_URL
    PORT: $PORT
    JWT_SECRET: $JWT_SECRET
    JWT_REFRESH_SECRET: $JWT_REFRESH_SECRET
    JWT_EXPIRES: $JWT_EXPIRES
    JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRES: $JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRES
    REDIS_HOST: $REDIS_HOST
    REDIS_PORT: $REDIS_PORT
    REDIS_PASSWORD: $REDIS_PASSWORD
    DB_HEALTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT: $DB_HEALTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT
    RAW_BODY_LIMITS: $RAW_BODY_LIMITS
    ELASTICSEARCH_API_KEY: $ELASTICSEARCH_API_KEY
    ELASTICSEARCH_URL: $ELASTICSEARCH_URL


package.json
{
  "name": "ormo-be",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
 "engines": {
  "node": ">=20.16.0"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.14.0",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/cqrs": "^10.2.7",
    "@nestjs/elasticsearch": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.4.0",
    "@nestjs/terminus": "^10.2.3",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^6.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.17.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "amqp-connection-manager": "^4.1.14",
    "amqplib": "^0.10.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cache-manager": "^5.7.4",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "ioredis": "^5.4.1",
    "joi": "^17.13.3",
    "nestjs-pino": "^4.1.0",
    "node-addon-api": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "pino-pretty": "^11.2.2",
    "rabbitmq-client": "^4.6.0",
    "redlock": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "winston": "^3.13.1",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.13",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.16",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prisma": "^5.17.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src/",
      "<rootDir>/libs/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@app/libs/common(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs/libs/common/src/$1",
      "^@app/common(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs/common/src/$1"
    }
  }
}


also added .npmrc file but no luck

still need help
